# Crossing Between two lines with error bars

Tags: regression, fitting

I have two sets of points with corresponding error bars and I want to find their estimated crossing coordinate including also an error.

Here's an example:

[image: Example Crossing with error]

The blue fit and the yellow fit would cross around $x = 17.35$, but I want to know what's the error $x=17.35 \pm \Delta x$

Comment: Having two sets of points with errors you can do a weighted fit of a line, $y=a_ix+b_i$, to each. Then the crossing is at $x=\frac{b_2-b_1}{a_1-a_2}$, whose error you can calculate via the law of error propagation.

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the upper and lower error lines for both curves, you will find a diamond. The width of the diamond will give you 2Δ.